# Reusing the same value inside of a Java Stream

Tags: java, math, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to use Java Streams to imitate an equation step-by-step. I have a plugin that will allow me to see the results at each step in the debugger and that is my end goal. I would also like to test what modifying specific numbers would do to the output

However, I need to reuse one value that is used at the 1st mapping function for the last mapping function, and I cannot figure out how to do it. I have commented out what I would like to do, but the compiler finds it incorrect.

Basically, I am testing the following mathematical function...

**`((2x + 10) / 2) - x = 5`**

```
List<Month> months = new ArrayList<>(12);

    months.add(new Month(1, "January"));
    months.add(new Month(2, "February"));
    months.add(new Month(3, "March"));
    months.add(new Month(4, "April"));
    months.add(new Month(5, "May"));
    months.add(new Month(6, "June"));
    months.add(new Month(7, "July"));
    months.add(new Month(8, "August"));
    months.add(new Month(9, "September"));
    months.add(new Month(10, "October"));
    months.add(new Month(11, "November"));
    months.add(new Month(12, "December"));

    months.stream()                                        //  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12
            .map((month) -> month.number * 2)              //  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24
            .map((product) -> product + 10)                // 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34
            .map((sum) -> sum / 2)                         //  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
     // --> .map((quotient) -> quotient - month.number)    //  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5
            .toArray();
```

Just to be clear, I am trying to reuse the `month.number` value.

**Edit**
Just to be clear, `month.number` represents `x` with the first `.map()`, I am showing the results of `2x` (`month.number * 2`).

Also, here is the code for `Month`

```
private class Month {

    int number;
    String name;

    public Month(int month, String name) {

        this.number = month;
        this.name = name;

    }
}
```

Comment: What does that *equation* have to do with month names?

Comment: oh sorry, `x = month.number`. Not name, but I plan on using the month name later on. Right now I am just using `month.number`

Comment: Have you considered introducing wrapper class to keep original x along with result of calculations at current step?

Comment: @VitalyZ I am rather new to functional programming; having only done simple maps and filters before. I am not certain how wrapper classes will help since nothing happens until the terminator function is triggered. How would the value be stored? I'm trying to wrap my head around that

Comment: Just a small remark: In step `.map((product) -> product + 10)` it should probably be _minus_ 10 instead of _plus_ 10.

Comment: @ChristophBöhme Yes, you are right that there is an error. However, my code is correct. I typed the equation wrong **above** the code. Will fix ^^

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski Please look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mismatch/19d20828a170d85b1dd65730e40f0604)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need several maps one after the other for the example you posted. Just do one map that does all that calculations (and you will have then the original month value).

If you anyway want to do it this way, then you will need that your maps do not return the number alone, but instead a pair of month/tmp_value.

There is not a java class specifically aimed to store pairs, but you can use the Map.Entry (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry) or, better, implement your own Pair class.

Comment: I will try this when I get home. Makes sense. But I do need to split it up. A plugin will show me step by step what happens. I cannot do that as one map function

Comment: I need to create a wrapper around Stream (i.e. `MonthStream`),  since no `map` function in the SDK allows for such return value. That is correct? I am looking at creating this `MonthStream` right now

Comment: no need for that stream. on the map method you can return whatever class you want, no restriction on that. The restricion is in the input only, map will take the element defined in the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the last comment, that is what I was looking for. As an additional question, is it possible to do this without the Pair? Where I only pass the values, but I can access the month anywhere in the stream? Would that be something like the `MonthStream` that I talked about earlier?

Comment: MonthStream would be more complex that you would want. If you don't to create a Pair class, you could reuse Abstract.SingleEntry class, which already allows for pairs (but IMHO this would be a lazy trick, since that's for Maps). Or you could just return an int array int[], puting the month as the first element of the array, and the temp value as the second element. The thing with int[] is that it can lead to confusions on long term, is less maintanable IMHO, specially if it starts being passed over other functions

Comment: Yeah, I saw I had to override a ton of methods for the `MonthStream` approach. Your way is the simplest that fits my needs. Thanks ^^. Also, for those that want code. Look at [VitalyZ's gist](https://gist.github.com/mismatch/19d20828a170d85b1dd65730e40f0604)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access variables from previous `map()`s, it means you separated `map()` calls unnecessarily. You can do everything in a single one:

```
 months.stream()                                
   .map(m -> ((m.number * 2) + 10)/2 - m.number)             
   .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

or step by step:

```
months.stream()                                     
  .map(m -> {
      int product = m.number * 2;
      int sum = product + 10;
      int quotient = sum / 2;
      int result = quotient - m.number;
      return result;
  }).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: If I didn't care about the step-by-step results (as indicated in the first 2 sentences), then this would be what I would have done.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski the approach would be the same, just perform the computation in a few steps. Check updated answer.